# How to send custom metric from collectd (stackdriver agent) to stackdriver

Tags: stackdriver, collectd

I can't send data to strackdriver. It's simple example.
I'm using syntax what I found in example for collectd.
Stackdriver documentation  don't have info about how to send custom data from exec module.
What am I doing wrong?

This is collectd.conf

```
LoadPlugin exec
<Plugin "exec">
    Exec "apache" "/etc/stackdriver/collectd.d/dir.sh"
</Plugin>
```

This is dir.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
FOLDER="/var/www/"
while true; do
  DU=$(du -shm ${FOLDER} | awk '{print $1}')
  echo "PUTVAL \"projects/project_name/custom.googleapis.com/folder/completesolar\" interval=60 N:${DU}"
  sleep 60
done
```

Script output

```
$/etc/stackdriver/collectd.d/dir.sh
PUTVAL "projects/project_name/custom.googleapis.com/folder/completesolar" interval:60 N:1155
```

I enabled debug mode and found this error:

```
[2018-09-21 00:45:55] utils_cmd_putval: handle_putval (fh = 0x3e71d8f040, buffer = PUTVAL "projects/project_name/custom.googleapis.com/folder/completesolar" interval=60 N:1155);
[2018-09-21 00:45:55] No such dataset registered: custom.googleapis.com/folder/completesolar
```

I created this metric and found it in stackdriver console:
http://joxi.ru/a2XlPGvi1VzJL2

This is json for creating my metric:

```
{
  "name": "projects/project_name/metricDescriptors/custom.googleapis.com/folder/completesolar",
  "metricKind": "GAUGE",
  "valueType": "DOUBLE",
  "unit": "By",
  "description": "Folder bytes used",
  "displayName": "Folder usage",
  "type": "custom.googleapis.com/folder/completesolar",
  "metadata": {
    "launchStage": "GA",
    "samplePeriod": "60s",
    "ingestDelay": "0s"
    }
}
```

Comment: Will it work if you add a filter chain and set MetaData? <Target "set"> # Specify the metric descriptor name: MetaData "stackdriver_metric_type" "custom.googleapis.com/folder/completesolar"
</Target>

Answer (score 1):

This should be work.

*/etc/stackdriver/collectd.d/dir.conf*

```xml
LoadPlugin exec
<Plugin "exec">
    Exec "apache" "/path/to/dir.sh"
</Plugin>

LoadPlugin target_set
PreCacheChain "PreCache"
<Chain "PreCache">
  <Rule "dir">
    <Match regex>
      Plugin "^exec$"
      PluginInstance "^dir$"
    </Match>
    <Target "set">
      MetaData "stackdriver_metric_type" "custom.googleapis.com/folder/completesolar"
      # MetaData "stackdriver_metric_type" "custom.googleapis.com/%{plugin_instance}/%{type_instance}"
      # MetaData "label:name" "dir usage"
    </Target>
  </Rule>
</Chain>
```

*/path/to/dir.sh*

```sh
#!/bin/bash
INTERVAL="$COLLECTD_INTERVAL"
HOSTNAME="$COLLECTD_HOSTNAME"
FOLDER="/var/www/"

while true; do
  DU=$(du -sm ${FOLDER} | awk '{print $1}')

  # https://collectd.org/documentation/manpages/collectd-exec.5.shtml
  # PUTVAL Identifier [OptionList] Valuelist
  # Identifier: <host>/<plugin>-<plugin_instance>/<type>-<type_instance>
  # Type: See /opt/stackdriver/collectd/share/collectd/types.db
  echo "PUTVAL ${HOSTNAME}/exec-dir/gauge-usage/ interval=${INTERVAL} N:${DU}"
  sleep "${INTERVAL}"
done
```

See below if you want to (pre) create or delete a metric.
https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/creating-metrics

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are following [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/custom-metrics-agent) to ingest exec metrics.   I think the rewrite rules did not work so the metric ends up being ingested though a regular agent metrics path, which rejects unrecognized metrics. You might need to [modify the metadata](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/custom-metrics-agent#writing_custom_metrics_with_the_agent) for your metric by using filter chain .  I would suggest you to revisit the [troubleshooting guide](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/custom-metrics-agent#troubleshooting).